# MySQL undefined alias with union select and alias

Tags: mysql

So I have this table, if I use this query everything is fine:

```
SELECT *
FROM `users` AS usr
WHERE usr.id = 9
ORDER BY usr.id ASC , usr.date DESC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

However, as soon as I try to use union select I get an error:

```
SELECT *
FROM `users` AS usr   
WHERE usr.id = 9
UNION ALL SELECT 1,2,3,4,5
ORDER BY usr.id ASC , usr.date DESC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

I get the error unknown column 'usr.id' in order clause.  How can I fix this so that the union select works with it?  Thanks.

EDIT: IS there any way to do it while keeping my original query in tact and not changing it too much?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM(SELECT *
     FROM `users` AS usr   
     WHERE usr.id = 9
     UNION ALL 
     SELECT 1,2,3,4,5) a
ORDER BY a.id ASC , a.date DESC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 0):

Second table doesn't have a column `id`. Do it like so:

```
SELECT id, ...
FROM `users` AS usr   
WHERE usr.id = 9
UNION ALL SELECT 1 id, ...
ORDER BY id ASC... DESC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```